# How can I use javascript to change all of the urls of an html site so that they work on a subdomain

Tags: javascript, url, subdomain

I'm wondering how can I use javascript to change all of the urls of an html site so that they work on a subdomain as a backup. For instance, if a site has a lot of internal links to urls like http://example.com, http://example.com/archives, http://example.com/about, etc., how could I change all of those to read something like http://backup.example.com. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are these all links `<a href=`? any `<form action=` or inline javascript? are all these links same origin? i.e. `<a href="http://example.com/archives">` is the same as `<a href="archives">` if the page domain is `http://example.com/` - in that case, remove the `http://example.com` from the links, and the page will work in any (sub)domain without requiring any changes

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstood your requirements then this could be a possible solution. See [Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

```js
function replaceSubdomain(url, subdomain) {
  return url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)(www\.)?([^.])*/, `$1$2${subdomain}`);
}

let allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
  //console.log(allLinks[i].href); 
  allLinks[i].href = replaceSubdomain(allLinks[i].href, 'backup.example');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Funny Quote Gen</title>

</head>

<body>

  I'm wondering how can I use javascript to change all of the urls of an html site so that they work on a subdomain as a backup. For instance, if a site has a lot of internal links to urls like
  <a href="http://example.com">example</a>,
  <a href="http://example.com/archives">archive</a>,
  <a href="http://example.com/about">about</a>, etc., how could I change all of those to read something like http://backup.example.com. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks
</body>

</html>
```

**OR** with class name approach- just add a class name on the `<a>` that you want to replace with subdomain like `<a class="replace_to_subdomain" href="http://example.com/contact">contact</a>`. See [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

```js
function replaceSubdomain(url, subdomain) {
  return url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)(www\.)?([^.])*/, `$1$2${subdomain}`);
}

let allLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('replace_to_subdomain');
for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
  //console.log(allLinks[i].href);
  allLinks[i].href = replaceSubdomain(allLinks[i].href, 'backup.example');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Funny Quote Gen</title>

</head>

<body>

  I'm wondering how can I use javascript to change all of the urls of an html site so that they work on a subdomain as a backup. For instance, if a site has a lot of internal links to urls like
  <a href="http://example.com">example</a>,
  <a class="replace_to_subdomain" href="http://example.com/archives">archive</a>,
  <a href="http://example.com/about">about</a> or
  <a class="replace_to_subdomain" href="http://example.com/contact">contact</a> , etc., how could I change all of those to read something like http://backup.example.com. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option looks like it will work, but I haven't had a chance yet to try it. When I run it above, it does what I want, and I think it will work although I don't quite understand the code. Also, would this work in reverse as well? As in, if at some point I wanted to go back from the subdomain to the primary domain, could I take the "backup" portion out of the urls so that they once again just read "example.com"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `class` for that. For example look the code bellow.

```js
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('wantToChange');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].href = "http://subdomain.com";
}
```

```html
<a href="http://link.com" class="wantToChange">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://link22.com" class="wantToChange">Link 2</a>
<a href="http://link.com" class="wantToChange">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to have to manually add the class to every link that I need to change, so this won't work for this situation.